# if statement giving errors when ran but not in idle

Tags: python

I making a if statement for my program and when it runs it gives an error. This is my code:

```
if num1 = num2:
    print('Equal')
```

Comment: Please provide the error and follow the guidelines for how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you've mixed up thw two operaters. = is used for assignment(such as x = 5). == is used to compare two values(like comparing x == y).

Answer (score 0):

when you compare in python its == not =